# How to unzip generated project from Spring Initializer?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

After unzipping project, I am getting message:

`Error: Cannot download 'https://start.spring.io/starter.zip?type=gradle-project&packaging=jar&javaVersion=11&language=java&bootVersion=2.2.4.RELEASE&groupId=com.korzhov&artifactId=core&name=core&version=0.0.1&description=Service&packageName=com.korzhov.core&dependencies=security&dependencies=actuator&dependencies=postgresql&dependencies=mail&dependencies=web&dependencies=data-jpa&dependencies=h2&dependencies=devtools&dependencies=thymeleaf&dependencies=lombok': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK`

What is causing this problem? It happens twice in a row.

Comment: Read timed out seems to explain it.

Comment: ..the `response: 200 OK` somewhat strange/misleading, though! (proxy/firewall ..intellij-settings!?)

Comment: Can you download using this link from browser? If you use proxies make sure it it configured in IDE Proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to some network/firewall configurations.
Often, it able to connect the maven repo, but not able to download any of the jars.

Try checking your local .m2 repository.

[image]